# firefox bug mouseenter/mouseleave

Tags: jquery, firefox, mouseevent

i already read many stuff about FF bug concerning mouse-movement events (enter, leave, cover, out etc.) But i dont realy understand the point and dont get how i can adopt the solutions for my case.

I have a div, representing a picture thumb. The idea is if this thumb is coverd by mouse it gets dark and a check icon in the corner of the picture become visible an can be clicked to mark that the picture is selected.

The structure is:

```
<div class='shadow_block'>
    <img class='shadow_pic' src="..."> <!-------picture -->
    <div class='shadow_back'></div>    <!-------covering dark layer -->
    <div class='shadow_select_block' data-clicked="0"> 
        <div class='shadow_select_pic'></div>  <!--check icon -->
        <div class='shadow_select_back'></div> <!--covering dark layer for the check icon -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And here are my handlers:

```
    $('#mydialog').on('mouseenter', '.shadow_block', function(event){
        $('.shadow_select_block', this).css('opacity', 1);
        $('.shadow_back', this).css('opacity', 0.3);

    });

    $('#mydialog').on('mouseleave', '.shadow_block', function(event){
        if ($(this).find('.shadow_select_block').data('clicked') === 0){
            $('.shadow_select_block', this).css('opacity', 0);
            $('.shadow_back', this).css('opacity', 0);
        }
    });

    $('#mydialog').on('mouseenter', '.shadow_select_block', function(event){
        $('.shadow_select_back', this).css('z-index', '1002');
    });

    $('#mydialog').on('mouseleave', '.shadow_select_block', function(event){
        $('.shadow_select_back', this).css('z-index', '1004');
    });
```

The problem is, when i move the mouse quickly over the shadow_block mouseenter and mouseleave fire and the shadow layer AND the shadow_select_block are shown and hidden.
When i move the mouse slowly out of the shadow_block only the shadow_select_block is hidden, shadow_back (the dark layer over the picture) is still shown.

No problems with Chrome...

Thx.